# Jupyter Notebook still running or dead

Tags: python

I am working on a project with a very big dataset (1.5M approx). In a cell I ran some NLP processing that I know it would take a lot of time. I was expecting around 24h max but it has now been 28hrs and it appears it is still running.
Is there a way to make sure that it is not dead and it is indeed still running? Of course I know about the [*], the dot next to the Kernel and the sand watch on the tab, but maybe they are frozen or something?

I just want to make sure that nothing happened maybe while I was sleeping and left it running throughout the night like losing connection or something.

Also I know about tqdm but since I am doing some pipes and multiprocessing, it cannot track progress.

Comment: Did you check the Jupyter Server log? You need to post the logs and relevant information for us to be able to help you.

Comment: It worths getting your code reporting periodically something, even "(timestamp) hey, I'm alive" and saving that to a log. [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module can help you.